# How to embed a webpage (indiegogo) in wordpress

Tags: javascript, html, css, wordpress, iframe

I have an upcoming indeogogo campaign.  I'd like to redirect people who support it not to the indiegogo site itself but rather to my own site where they'll see it, but still have the added benefit of the top nav bar and it's links to other portions of the page.
I saw that there's something called iframe but when i tried it it seemed to only frame the external page in a box which meant to see it in full you'd have to do additional scrolling which really destroys the functionality.
Any ideas here?
Thanks!

Sample code: `<iframe src="https://www.indiegogo.com/projects/xyz123"></iframe>`
I actually can't really get that to work either.
How do people link to other sites but keep a navbar at the top?  I've seen link referral people do it, like adfly

Comment: @user9899376 post your code so we can take a look.

Answer (score 0):

You need to configure your web server for (X-Frame-Options)-response header, due to the same-origin policy. Take a look at the information here at this link -- https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/X-Frame-Options.

Answer (score 0):

You have to use indiegogo's embed tool: https://support.indiegogo.com/hc/en-us/articles/527366-How-to-Add-a-Widget-to-your-Blog

First, make sure your Wordpress Blog has the Wordpress iframe plug-in installed:

Sign into your Wordpress blog.
Go to http://wordpress.org/plugins/iframe/ to install the iframe plug-in
Second, generate the code to embed your campaign widget:

Go back to your Indiegogo campaign page
Make sure you're logged in your Indiegogo account
Click on the "embed" button underneath your main pitch video or image. The Embed button is only available after your campaign has launched.
Copy the link you just generated, it should look like this "`<iframe src="https://www.indiegogo.com/project/xxx/embedded" width="222px" height="445px" frameborder="0" scrolling="no"></iframe>`"
Third, insert code in your Wordpress blog:

Next, sign back into your Wordpress blog.
Go to your blog dashboard.
Click on the page, where you'd like to add the campaign widget
Paste the link that you have generated on Indiegogo

Comment: I just tried the following:
<iframe src="https://www.indiegogo.com/projects/bear-city-3/x/6128951" name="iframe" scrolling="auto" frameborder="no" align="center" height = "600px" width = "800px">
</iframe>

Nothing showed in the screen

Comment: Not what I'm looking for. Looking for the whole page within my page not the widget which just redirects to the external site.

Answer (score -1):

If you're using jQuery you can try using jQuery get() or load  methods to display the result in a div like:

```
jQuery.get("yoururl", function(data){
    jQuery("#content").html(data);
}
```

OR

```
jQuery("#content").load("yoururl");
```

Comment: Loading the source of the page and loading the page are not the same thing.